# Markov chain recurrence solving

Tags: recurrence-relations, markov-chains, recursion

I am given a transition matrix for the markov chain 
on the space state $X=\{1,2\}$
$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1-a & a\\
b & 1-b
\end{pmatrix}$
We are asked to find $P^n$ as a hint I am told to notice that: 
\begin{equation}p_n=P^n(1,1)=\mathbb{P}(X_n=1|X_0=1)\end{equation} and use recursion 
$$p_n=p_{n-1}(1-a)+(1-p_{n-1})b$$
So I understood that first hint is just form me to really see what am I calculating and that I have to do the same for (1,2), (2,1), (2,2) as well. And second is just total probability formula, because $X_{n-1}=2$ with probability $1-p_{n-1}$ we "get to" $X_n=1$ with prob. $b$ similarly $X_{n-1}=1$ with probability $p_{n-1}$ and we "get to" $X_n=1$ with prob. $1-a$.

I know how to solve this diagonalizing P, but I cannot do this the way they want me to i.e. solve the recursion. I tried to guess the formula and proved it inductively and I ended up with some ugly summation not worth quoting here, and failed proving inductively that it is right.

So the question is how to solve this recursion?

Comment: If you let $c=1-a-b$, you can rewrite the recurrence as $p_n=cp_{n-1}+b$. This is a simple linear recurrence with initial condition $p_0=1$; do you know how to solve such recurrences?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott nope, but I will google it. ;)

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601046/not-deducing-a-closed-form-for-recurrence-relation-correctly/1601493#1601493) gives one elementary method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, we have

\begin{align*}
  p_n &= p_{n - 1} (1 - a - b) + b \\
      &= [p_{n - 2} (1 - a - b) + b] (1 - a - b) + b = p_{n - 2} (1 - a - b)^2 + b \sum_{k = 0}^1 (1 - a - b)^k \\
      &\vdots \\
      &= p_0 (1 - a - b)^n + b \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (1 - a - b)^k \\
      &= (1 - a - b)^n + b \left(\frac{1 - (1 - a - b)^n}{1 - (1 - a - b)} \right) \\
      &= (1 - a - b)^n + \frac{b}{a + b} (1 - (1 - a - b)^n) \\
      &= \frac{a (1 - a - b)^n + b}{a + b}.
\end{align*}